# Generate alpha numeric sequence irrespective of input sequence length

Tags: java

Generate the next possible alpha numeric sequence for a given input sequence irrespective of input sequence length and irrespective of position of alpha numerals.
It accept alpha numeric input and generate the next sequence that is what the whole idea.

```
Few examples, input sequence -> expected output

AA -> AB
A0 -> A1
Z9 -> A0
A1Z -> A2A
ZZZ -> AAA
ZZ9 -> AA0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
private static final char[] SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY = { 'Z', '9', 'A', '0' };

if(inputSequence.matches(ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX)) {
    StringBuilder nextSequece = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isIncremented = false;
    char ch = 0;
    for (int i = inputSequence.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ch = inputSequence.charAt(i);
        if (ch != SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[0] && ch != SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[1] && !isIncremented) {
            nextSequece.append((char) (ch + 1));
            isIncremented = true;
        } else if (ch == SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[0] && !isIncremented) {
            nextSequece.append(SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[2]);
        } else if (ch == SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[1] && !isIncremented) {
            nextSequece.append(SEQUENCE_CHAR_ARRAY[3]);
        } else {
            nextSequece.append(ch);
        }
    }
    nextSequece = nextSequece.reverse();
}
```